# Using wildcard when scraping data from XPath in Python

Tags: python, xpath

Is there a way to scrape data using a wildcard in the xpath. For example, I would like to include any additional text that may be after the `/p` in the xpath here:

```
value = tree.xpath('//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/p/text()') or 'none'
```

So, I would imagine something like this:

```
value = tree.xpath('//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/p/*.*text()') or 'none'
```

In some cases I have found an extra span element like this example, but it's not always there:

```
...[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/p/span/text()') or 'none'
```

Comment: maybe something like this? ```value = tree.xpath('//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/p//text()') or 'none'```

Comment: @MadRay that seems to have worked. Thanks!